# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 5: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, utf-8

I am using Python 2.7 and had this error that I can't fix. I am trying to download HTMLs from a page and the next button looks like this : Next »

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Said&Nour\Desktop\Documents\PythonFiles\LebanonParsing\Al Rifai\alrifai.py", line 109, in <module>
    if PageP.find('a',attrs={'title':'Next »'}) is None:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1300, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1321, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 602, in _find_all
    strainer = SoupStrainer(name, attrs, text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1420, in __init__
    normalized_attrs[key] = self._normalize_search_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1434, in _normalize_search_value
    return value.decode("utf8")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 5: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is slightly off-format from how stack-overflow works. Please rephrase the question to be "UnicodeDecodeError received using python 2.7 BeautifulSoup4 library" or something similar. Before you ask the question, you should google this error, as there are many stackoverflow answers for this already, and chances are you will find a solution there. If you can't find any, then you should post a question here, otherwise use the massive archive of answers and questions to your advantage.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)